# Variable cannot be called outside of MouseListener constructor

Tags: java, variables, constructor, mouseevent, mouselistener

I'm trying to create a Java program utilizing Swing. One of the things I'm trying to accomplish is using a MouseListener to get the index of a clicked item in a JList and retrieve a variable associated with index of the array. My problem is that when I try to call the variable outside of the MouseListener, it does not get recognized. My code being:

```
public class UserListPanel extends JPanel {

LibraryController ctrl = new LibraryController();
JScrollPane scrollpane;
public int userid;
public String userName;

public UserListPanel(final Borrower[] borrowersArray) {

    String userArray [] = new String [borrowersArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
        userArray[i] = borrowersArray[i].getName();
    }

    JList userList = new JList(userArray);
    scrollpane = new JScrollPane(userList);
    this.add(scrollpane);

    // Adds a mouse click listener to assign values from the JList to a variable on click
    userList.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
            JList userList = (JList)evt.getSource();
            if (evt.getClickCount() >= 0) {
                int index = userList.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint());
                ListModel dlm = userList.getModel();
                Object item = dlm.getElementAt(index);
                userList.ensureIndexIsVisible(index);
                userid = borrowersArray[index].getbID();
                userName = borrowersArray[index].getName();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, userName);
            }
        }
    });
}

userid = borrowersArray[index].getbID();

}
```

Within the MouseListener constructor I am able to correctly get the variable and store it within the userid variable, for example, and my JOptionPane confirms this by returning a number. Hoewever, outside of the constructor, the integer "index" is not recognized and thus if I were to call userid, it would return null. How would I go about having a copy of index outside of MouseListener?

Answer (score 1):

If you want `index` outside `mouseClicked` method ( not a constructor) then you should initialize it outside the `mouseClicked` method and  assign it a value inside the `mouseClicked` method and then you will be able to get that `index` outside the constructor.

You are declaring and initializing `index` inside the `mouseClicked` method so that variable's scope is upto the `mouseClicked` method and hence it is not available outside its scope i.e. outside the `mouseClicked` method.

```
public UserListPanel(final Borrower[] borrowersArray) {
    int index=0;
    String userArray [] = new String [borrowersArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
        userArray[i] = borrowersArray[i].getName();
    }

      ..... all other stuff
}
```

Comment: actually, no, upon further inspection, it does not work. The variable does not ever obtain a value from the MouseListener constructor and defaults to 0. When I call username, for example, it will always return with the name associated with the first index of the list (0).  Evidently, the index outside of the constructor never gets passed the integer from inside.

Comment: are you initializing it to some value at the time of declaration

Comment: No, it is just declared as int index. Java defaults the value to 0. Because 0 is the first entry of an array and the first entry of the JList is what is being returned, I think the assignment of value within the constructor is ignored outside of the constructor.

Comment: declare and intialize it at the start of your constructor, see my edited answer

Comment: By moving int index = 0; into the UserListPanel(final Borrower[] borrowersArray) constructor, I receive an error on all instances of index saying that I cannot refer to a non-final variable index inside an inner class that is defined in another method. However, by declaring index final, index = userList.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint()) gets an error because I cannot define index (which is final) in an enclosing type.

Answer (score 0):

The `index` variable is declared within the `MouseListener` implementation. Therefore the compiler does not understand of any `index` variable where you are trying to access it.

To overcome this issue try declaring the `index` outside the Listener implementation.

Ex

```
public class UserListPanel extends JPanel {

  LibraryController ctrl = new LibraryController();
  JScrollPane scrollpane;
  public int userid;
  public String userName;
  public int index ; //declare it as a global (member) variable
...
}
```

Comment: Apparently I overlooked that. Thank you for your help!